# Implementing Join in this query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I currently have a query to find if one employee is working on more than one assignment, and returns the names of the employees.

```
SELECT Eid, Count(Eid),
(SELECT Ename from Employee where Employee.Eid = Assignment.Eid) as EName
FROM Assignment
GROUP BY Eid HAVING Count(Eid) > 1;
```

Employee table has EID, and EName field. Assignment has EID and AssignmentNum.


Currently it works, but I think it can be written better with Inner Join, but I can't seem to compose a query with join that works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just do:

```
SELECT a.Eid, Count(*), e.EName
FROM Assignment a JOIN
     Employee e
     ON e.Eid = a.Eid
GROUP BY a.Eid, e.name
HAVING Count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.ename, a.Eid, Count(a.Eid),
from Employee 
Inner join assignment as a on e.Eid = a.Eid
GROUP BY a.Eid 
HAVING Count(a.Eid) > 1;
```

You had the necessary join logic within the subquery.